# Python, correct way to pass variables between functions

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to make a game in python using the pygame module.

```
def draw_character(self, color, box):
    rect = pygame.Rect(box)
    pygame.draw.rect(self.game.display, (color), pygame.Rect(rect))
    return rect
```

and in the draw_character function preserves the collision shape of the character

move function:

```
def move(self, rect):
   if rect.bottom >= self.game.DISPLAY_H:
        print("work")
```

and finally I call the function like this

```
self.move(self.draw_character((221,171,177), (self.f1, self.f2, 60, 60)))
```

Is there another way I can call the rect variable or am I already doing this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Character` class and make the rectangle (`rect`) and the color an attribute of the class:

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(rect, color, game):
        self.rect = rect
        self.color = color
        self.game = game

    def move(self):
        if self.rect.bottom >= self.game.DISPLAY_H:
            print("work")
   
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.game.display, self.color, self.rect)
```

Create an instance of the class `Character`. Move and draw the character in the application loop:

```py
character = Character((221,171,177), (self.f1, self.f2, 60, 60))

while True:

    # [...]

    character.move()
    character.draw()
```

Comment: thank you master!, i will re-edit my code like this,[but my code wasn't bad either:)]

Comment: @Django You can simplify one line. Change `pygame.draw.rect(self.game.display, (color), pygame.Rect(rect))` to `pygame.draw.rect(self.game.display, color, rect)`. Try to write many small classes instead of one large class (God-Object)

Comment: Actually I can't refactor the code like this, I already have a character class and required operations.
i do this in the loop of the character class ,thanks for replying anyway

Comment: @Django Anyway, you can create a `self.rect` attribute. So you don't have to pass it to the methods.